# Logical Masking in Matlab - How to (instantly) index concatenated Matlab array?

Tags: matlab, indexing, struct, concatenation, mask

### Data Structure:

I have a struct array `s` with several fields `s.x`, `s.y` and `s.z`.
Please consider the following structure properties of the struct!:

(1) Fields in the same row have same sized single vectors:

```
length(s(i).x)=length(s(i).y)=length(s(i).z)
```

(2) Single vectors in fields may vary in size across rows:

```
length(s(i).x)~=length(s(j).x)
length(s(i).y)~=length(s(j).y)
length(s(i).z)~=length(s(j).z)
```

---

### Problem:

I would like to create a logical mask based on one of the fields, e.g. `s.z` and apply it to the entire struct array. One way is to do the following:

```
mask = [s.z] > 0;
s_concatenated = [s.x; s.y; s.z]';
mask_applied2struct = s_concatenated(mask);
```

Now my Question is whether **there is a way to apply a logical mask to a struct data type in Matlab?** Perhaps in following Fashion, e.g.:

```
mask_applied2struct = s([s.z] > 0)
```

or

```
mask_applied2struct = [s]([s.z] > 0)
```

So, basically I am interested in an instantaneous way to concatenate a struct and apply a mask to it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `s_concatenated = [s.dx(mask); s.dy(mask); s.dz(mask)]';`?

Comment: Because concatenating will remove my data structure

Answer (score 4):

You can use `structfun` to apply a function to each field of your structure. `structfun`is basically a hidden for loop.

Example:

```
%random structure with size(x) = size(y) = size(z)
s.x = round(rand(4,4)*2-1);
s.y = round(rand(4,4)*2-1);
s.z = round(rand(4,4)*2-1);

%create a logical mask
mask = s.x>=0;

%apply the mask to each field
s_new = structfun(@(p) p(mask),s,'UniformOutput',0)
```

Comment: thanks! *But please consider my (crucial) edit!* - with my data structure I get the following error upon mask creation acc. to you (with mask = s.x>=0;): "Error using  >= 
Too many input arguments."

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi: This code is for a *scalar* struct, if your struct has more than one element, you need to write another loop over those: `for ii=1:numel(s); apply code over s(ii); end`. -- And please don't say "but loops are slow", they are not!

Comment: But loops are slow :D